# Django how to perform a query to get all occourences where object 1 has a foreign key on object 2 and a certain object 2 has a property

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Okay, so I've got a question about performing queries. So, I've got one object called Job. A Job as a foreign key on StatusUpdate, meaning a single job can have many StatusUpdates. Basically, I need to get all Jobs with a LAST StatusUpdate with a certain property. I know that I can easily get all Jobs that have any StatusUpdate with a certain property like this:

```py
Job.objects.all().filter(statusupdate__status="Certain Property")
```

But this will get jobs that have any StatusUpdate with status of certain property. I want to get only jobs with a last StatusUpdate with a status of certain property. Is it possible to do this with a single query? I read the through the Django documentation and couldn't find anything.

Thank you!

Diego

Edit:

Let me clarify a little more exactly what I want to do. So I have a task assignment system. Each job has status updates as it progresses. When the job reaches a certain phase, say phase A, it gets a status update of "Phase A". I need to get all jobs where the status update was "Phase A". I would rather not do it with a bunch of python for loops because that's slow and inefficient. I also would prefer not to have to do it in raw SQL.

Edit 2:

Here some of my code is:

Job:

```py
class Job(models.Model):
    jobtype = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published', default=timezone.now)
```

Job Status:

```py
class JobStatus(models.Model):
    creation_time = models.DateTimeField('creation time', default=timezone.now)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

A job can have any number of `JobStatus`es. So I don't know the index of the last `JobStatus`, and I need to get all jobs with a certain last `JobStatus`.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. I understand in part with your code snippet, but not fully.

Comment: I can't make sense of "But this will get jobs that have any StatusUpdate with status of certain property. I want to get only jobs with a last StatusUpdate with a status of certain property."

Comment: I added a little more detail to my post, does that clarify?

Comment: Are there a finite number of StatusUpdates? Do you have them all defined/listed out?

Comment: Your edit is more of a "this is what I am doing and how I am doing it" - like full logic of how it works. What we need is how this relates to each other - a schema and more clarity on the problem itself. As of right now, the best I can figure that you want might be: `Job.objects.all().filter(id="some id", statusupdate__status="Certain Property")`

Comment: Maybe even better said is, we need more details. What is the problem and how can we recreate it. You can set up a hypothetical situation. For instance, I have a schema like `a` that relates to `b`. `a` has these properties and `b` has these. How can I do x or y with `a` and `b`?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! I added some more details and some code.